# URIs underscores to dashes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Please help. Should be simple for those who knows and understands. I just need .htaccess rewrite rule to replace ALL underscores to dashes in one redirect operation. I put

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301]
```

but it replaces one by one, if URL has five underscores it forces 5 redirects! Is it possible, in the same rewrite rule (which replaces _ with -) search for string and replace it too? Example:

```
host.com/i_want_it_to_be_replaced.html ->
host.com/i-want-it-to-be-replaced.html
```

and, if it sees "i_want" or "i-want" it replaces it with "force":

```
host.com/i_want_it_to_be_replaced.html ->
host.com/force-it-to-be-replaced.html
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule !_ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule (.*)i[_-]want(.*) /$1force$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L]
```